# Settings for zbrush-like Layer brush?

Tags: sculpting

In Zbrush there is a brush that doesn't overlap upon itself, it can make for some smooth uninterrupted strokes. I was wondering if Blender had anything of the sort, where the depth sort of levels off and it doesn't continue to build up. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Layer Brush

You can find it in the Brush browser:

[image]

From the [Blender reference manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting/sculpting/introduction.html#sculpt-brushes):

> This brush is similar to Draw, except that the height of the displacement layer is capped. This creates the appearance of a solid layer being drawn. This brush does not draw on top of itself; a brush stroke intersects itself. Releasing the mouse button and starting a new stroke will reset the depth and paint on top of the previous stroke.

**Persistent base** option **enabled** will allow to sculpt without overlaps.

See the different behavior in the image sequence below:

[image]

Remember to set the **Intensity** of the brush to **1**, or the stroke will not reach the "capping" level, leading to an accumulation when you draw upon an already sculpted area.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I enable 'set persistent base' ? [I'm using 2.76 and don't see it](http://puu.sh/lRRyo/e41c9852a2.png)

Comment: They removed it it looks like. Instead they seem to have made that the default, and made a setting to change it to accumulate.

Comment: I see, thanks. Though I still can't replicate the behavior in Carlo's gif, where multiple strokes go on top of eachother without build up.

Comment: Aha, so multi-res prevents it. Got it working, thanks

Comment: @Carlo Just out of Interest: *Multires Modifier?* Yes or No?

Comment: @poor With Multires Modifier there isn't the persistent base option (has it ever been?), so I think it's not currently possible to avoid overlaps between two different strokes with this method, but only during the same stroke. In the gif, I used a plane without multires (didn't tought of that)

Comment: I was able to find only this [task](https://developer.blender.org/T20376) where is stated that the combo Multires&Persistent base is not working yet (2009). Is it now possible? @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ  Were you able to avoid overlap between different two strokes with Multires?